# RSS feed publish date-time (GMT) to Unix timestamp format using PHP

Tags: php, database, rss

How do convert RSS feed publish date-time (GMT) to Unix timestamp using PHP?

I need to store the date into my table in a `TIMESTAMP` data type column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would it be an option to use the PHP functions to generate a Unix Timestamp (ie seconds since Unix Epoch) and then let MySQL handle it from there?

**PHP:** - [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$timestamp = strtotime( 'Sat, 07 Sep 2002 09:42:31 GMT' ); // = 1031391751
```

**MySQL:** - [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
... `timestamp` = FROM_UNIXTIME( 1031391751 ) ...
```

Comment: No idea why this has less votes than Alix's answer - which does not address the question asked as well as this one.

Answer (score 2):

From [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html):

> TIMESTAMP columns are displayed in the
>   same format as DATETIME  columns. In
>   other words, the display width is
>   fixed at 19 characters, and the format
>   is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.

The [RSS 2.0 specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) states that:

> All date-times in RSS conform to the
>   Date and Time Specification of RFC
>   822, with the exception that the year
>   may be expressed with two characters
>   or four characters (four preferred).

---

So if we have the following RSS date:

```
$timeRSS = 'Sat, 07 Sep 2002 09:42:31 GMT'; // RFC 822
```

We need to do the following to convert it to MySQL `TIMESTAMP` format:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT'); // make sure we are using the same timezone
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($timeRSS)); // 2002-09-07 09:42:31
```

Comment: From what I remember, the "r" format in date() outputs RFC2822-compliant datetimes; might be slightly easier than specifying it longhand...

Comment: @Matt: `date('r')` = `Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200`, that's not compatible with MySQL `TIMESTAMP` format.

Comment: Sorry, I was clearly reading before I'd drunk my coffee, and skipped a line or two.